# Subdirectories, slashes and single files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

first if someone founds a better title...go for it! 
The question is, i'm trying to setup mod rewrite so that all these are translated to

`http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/metadata.php`

preserving the query string parameters

- http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata
- http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata/wetheaverdirstructure
- http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata/
- http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata?wetheaver=parameter
- http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata/wetheaverdirstructure?wetheaver=parameter
- http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata/?wetheaver=parameter

I doged for hours through the internet with various tests but not one of the tenth i tryed worked...
(the space before mysite is only to allow posting on Stackoverflow... think it does not exists!)
Can someone give me some hint?
Thank you,
Enrico

(Changed the title)

Comment: Seems like the basic URL structure is `http:// mysite/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata` and as long as it matches, the segment after `/$metadata/` can be anything. ¿Is that right?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, exactly, and in case some query string it must be passed to the destination file (without the "extra" path")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !metadata\.php          [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/phpnuget/nuget/\$metadata  [NC] 
RewriteRule  .*     phpnuget/nuget/metadata.php   [L]
```

It will map silently any URL like this one:

`http://mysite.com/phpnuget/nuget/$metadata/anything`

To:

`http://mysite.com/phpnuget/nuget/metadata.php` removing the last `anything` segment.

If the incoming URL holds a query, it will be appended to `metadata.php` automatically in query format. i.e. `?this=is&a=query`

Just in case, there is NO need for the QSA flag.

To make the substitution URL permanent and visible, replace the last [L] with [L,R=301]